# NaN instead of number for my loading issue

Tags: jquery

I tried to create a code that adds 2 percent each time a component is loaded in, but instead of showing that number increment, I get `NaN`. Why is that?

```
//Define variable
var PercentLoaded = 0;

//When a component loads
var PercentLoaded = PercentLoaded+2;
//Print value
$('#LoadProgressMessage').html('<h6>'+ PercentLoaded + '% Loaded</h6>');
```

Thanks for all your help everybody!

Comment: code shown is over simplified, you may have scope problem, show more code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try not to redeclare your variable when you increment it :

```
//Define variable
var PercentLoaded = 0;

//When a component loads
/*var*/ PercentLoaded = PercentLoaded + 2;
```

Comment: If that makes much sense. The code should work fine by all means. (Not a DV:r)

Comment: It may depend on the js engine. I've tested it in chrome and it works just fine, but I can't find any other issues with his code.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the variable is no longer in scope. The code you provided should work ok by itself, but you probably have something like this in the actual code:

```
$( function() {
    var PercentLoaded = 0;

    // PercentLoaded is in scope only up to here
});

function whatever() {
    var PercentLoaded = PercentLoaded + 2;  
   // The original PercentLoaded is no longer in scope
}
```

Comment: Thanks Juhana, I didn't try this as Gion's explanation did the trick, however I appreciate the effort!